# Test Ignored:: java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: groovy, spock

I am working on API Automation with Spock framework and coding area is in JAVA Groovy; Why am I getting the error after running each case (Class)
The error is as Below:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:**LOCAL
>   PATH**\src\test\resources\CitiesData.csv (The system cannot find the
>   path specified)

Test Ignored
Test Ignored
Test Ignored
Test Ignored
Test Ignored

Comment: Without a simple example that we can run showing what you have and what you're doing, it's going to be really hard to answer this

Comment: Tim is right. I am going to dare a wild guess anyway: because the path is wrong and the specified file does not exist.